# MOSTRAR MAX,MIN de varias columnas sql 2008

Tags: sql-server

```
select nombre,Company,isnull([4],0) as 'ABRIL',isnull([2],0) as 'FEBRERO',isnull([9],0) as 'SETIEMBRE',
'TOTAL' = (isnull([4],0)+isnull([2],0)+isnull([9],0)),PROMEDIO = ((isnull([4],0)+isnull([2],0)+isnull([9],0)))/3,
'MAXIMO' = (CASE WHEN isnull([4],0) > isnull([2],0) AND isnull([4],0) > isnull([9],0) THEN isnull([4],0) ELSE 
CASE WHEN isnull([2],0) > isnull([4],0) AND isnull([2],0) > isnull([4],0) THEN isnull([2],0) ELSE 
CASE WHEN isnull([9],0) > isnull([4],0) AND isnull([9],0) > isnull([2],0) THEN isnull([9],0) ELSE 0 
END END END)
from
(select e.firstname 'nombre',c.CompanyName 'Company',od.UnitPrice 'CANTIDAD'
,DATEPART(MONTH,O.OrderDate) as DATA_MES 
from Employees e,Customers c,orders o,[Order Details] od
where
o.CustomerID = c.CustomerID and 
o.EmployeeID = e.EmployeeID and
od.OrderID = o.OrderID
group by e.firstname,c.CompanyName,od.UnitPrice,O.OrderDate
) AS MESTABLE
PIVOT(
SUM(CANTIDAD) 

FOR DATA_MES IN ([4], [2], [9])
)AS PIV_MES
```

Necesito hallar el mínimo de estos 3 meses quería hacerlo de la misma manera que halle el máximo?? 
Alguien sabe otra forma quizás más simplificada de hacerlo?

Answer (score 3):

Uff, hay varias cosas que arreglar en tu consulta.

Primero que todo, te recomiendo siempre usar el esquema de la tabla como prefijo (en este caso, estoy asumiendo que es dbo). Por otro lado, deberías usar joins explícitos en vez de estos joins implícitos (que ya están deprecados hace más de 10 años).

Finalmente, no veo el motivo de realizar un pivot, si después la verdad es que no se usa. El código que yo usaría es el siguiente:

```
WITH CTE AS
(
    SELECT  e.firstname Nombre,
            c.CompanyName Company,
            DATEPART(MONTH,O.OrderDate) Mes,
            SUM(od.UnitPrice) Cantidad
    FROM dbo.Employees e
    INNER JOIN dbo.orders o
        ON o.EmployeeID = e.EmployeeID
    INNER JOIN dbo.Customers c
        ON o.CustomerID = c.CustomerID
    INNER JOIN dbo.[Order Details] od
        ON od.OrderID = o.OrderID
    GROUP BY e.firstname,
             c.CompanyName,
             od.UnitPrice
)
SELECT  Nombre,
        Company,
        MAX(CASE WHEN Mes = 2 THEN Cantidad END) Febrero,
        MAX(CASE WHEN Mes = 4 THEN Cantidad END) Abril,
        MAX(CASE WHEN Mes = 9 THEN Cantidad END) Septiembre,
        MAX(Cantidad) Maximo,
        MIN(Cantidad) Minimo
FROM CTE
WHERE Mes IN (2,4,9)
GROUP BY Nombre,
         Company
;
```

Comment: Los `JOIN` implícitos oficialmente fueron deprecados en 1992 :O

Comment: @Flxtr entonces, técnicamente estoy bien… `más de 10 años` ;)

Comment: Excelente, gracias por tus recomendaciones ... he estado viendo y no cumple el  MAX(Cantidad) Maximo, MIN(Cantidad) Minimo, me halla el MAX(SUM(od.UnitPrice) Cantidad) igualmente el MIN(SUM(od.UnitPrice) Cantidad)  y debería hallar MAX(2,4,9) de esos 3 meses o los meses elegidos igualmente en el mínimo.... eso es lo quería hallar.